# Question about Ordering of a Tree

Tags: set-theory

I am looking at the following proof that "If there is a Souslin tree, then there is a Souslin line."

The author uses the following Lemma to deal with a normal Souslin tree instead of a Souslin tree.

**Lemma 2.6**
If there exists a Souslin tree $T$, then there exists a normal Souslin tree; that is, a Souslin tree $T'$ which satisfies the following properties:

1.
For every $x \in T'$ and $\alpha >$ ht(x) there is an $y \in T'$ with ht(y) = $\alpha$ and $y > x$.

2.
If ht(x) = ht(y) = $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, then $\{s \in T : s < x \} = \{s \in T : s < y \}$ implies $x = y$.

3.
If $x \in T'$ is not a maximal element then it has an infinite number of immediate successors.

4.
$T'$ has a least element.

Here starts the proof:

**Proof**

If there is a Souslin tree, then there is a normal Souslin tree by Lemma 2.6, so let $T$ be a normal Souslin tree.

The line $L$ will consist of the set of all branches of $T$ with a suitable linear order. Let $\mathcal{N} (t)$ denote the set of immediate successors of $t$. Since $T$ is normal, each $\mathcal{N} (t)$ is countably infinite; pick a linear order $\prec$ so that $\mathcal{N} (t)$ with this order is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $a,b$ be branches. If $a \neq b$, then the first ordinal for which they differ is a successor ordinal $\alpha + 1$ by (2) of the Lemma; so, let $t \in a \cap b$ be at level $\alpha$ and let $a_{\alpha} \in a$, $b_{\alpha} \in b$ be its immediate successors in $a$ respectively $b$; we define $a < b$ iff $a_{\alpha} \prec b_{\alpha}$. This defines a linear order.

My question is:
If $t$ is at a certain level say $\alpha$ then its immediate successors would be at level $\alpha + 1$. How can two immediate successors have a linear order, which he calls $\prec$ if both of the immediate successors $a_{\alpha}$ and $b_{\alpha}$ are on the same level? I thought that elements on the same level are not comparable. If you could please help me see what I am thinking wrong, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Go back to the second paragraph of the proof:

> Since $T$ is normal, each $\mathcal{N}(t)$ is countably infinite; pick a linear order $\prec$ so that $\mathcal{N}(t)$ with this order is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

He’s simply assigning a linear order to each $\mathcal{N}(t)$ for $t\in T$. It might be clearer to complicate the notation just a little. Given $t\in T$, let $\prec_t$ be any linear order on $\mathcal{N}(t)$ such that $\langle\mathcal{N}(t)\prec_t\rangle$ is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ with its usual order. These orders $\prec_t$ have nothing to do with the tree order: they’re additional orders imposed on the sets $\mathcal{N}(t)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that he was dealing with the ordering of the tree!

Comment: @Rishie: You’re welcome!